# Marklogic XQuery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, xquery, marklogic

I am trying to port an implementation in XQuery onto JS. There is this piece of code in XQuery:

```
document{$item}/node()
```

that retrieves an XML document.

Could any one please let me know how an equivalent implementation using MarkLogic JS API could look like?

Answer (score 4):

The XQuery appears to be constructing an XML document instead of retrieving it.

If so, the equivalent Server-Side JavaScript would be:

```
new NodeBuilder().addDocument(item).toNode().root
```

For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/NodeBuilder.addDocument

To retrieve a document, `cts.doc()` is useful.  To retrieve many documents in a single call, use `fn.doc()`

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks very much! Let me take a look at the link